# Constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have been given the question $y'' - 9y' = 9e^{9x}$ to solve. Per my knowledge, this is a second order non-homogeneous differential equation. By using the method of undetermined coefficients, I am supposed to find the solution of the homogeneous $+$ the particular solution of the non homogeneous. The homogeneous led me to $y = c_1 + c_2e^{9x}$.

How do I proceed from this point?

Comment: Make the guess (ansatz, rather) that the "particular solution" takes the form $Ke^{9x}.$ That is, suppose $y_p = y + Ke^{9x}$. Now solve for $K$.

Comment: There is an easier method: Substitute $u=y'$, then you obtain a first order linear (non-homogeneous) ODE. You can solve such with the integrating factor method (for example).

Answer (score 1):

For the particular solution, try : 
$$y_p=Axe^{9x}$$

---

Another way
$$y'' - 9y' = 9e^{9x}$$
$$y''e^{-9x} - 9y' e^{-9x}= 9$$
$$(y'e^{-9x})'= 9$$
Integrate
$$(y'e^{-9x})= 9x+K_1$$
$$y'=e^{9x}(9x+K_1)$$
Integrate again
$$y=9\int e^{9x}xdx+K_1e^{9x}+K_2$$
$$\boxed{y(x)=e^{9x}x+K_1e^{9x}+K_2}$$